# .animate frameset in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, frameset

I'm trying to change frameset cols by jquery .animate . But it's not working as an animate, it changes the cols immediately.

Is there anyway to animate frameset cols property?

here is my code,

```
function hideit() 
{
var myframeset = window.top.document.getElementById("fs");
$(myframeset).animate({
    cols: "*,0"
  }, 1500 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you **can't** animate the `cols` property.
`$.animate` has been built to animate css properties, and `cols` isn't one of them.